# $in is not working in loopback

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I have an array of string as follows:

```
['57b69c9d4ae615ef0e312af6','57b69bf477b8e5cd0eb38c88'];
```

I am converting this into ObjectId as follows:

```
var objectIds = [];
  for(var i=0; i<expenseIds.length; i++){
    var _id = new ObjectId(expenseIds[i]);
    objectIds.push(_id);
  }
```

objectIds:

```
[ 57b69c9d4ae615ef0e312af6, 57b69bf477b8e5cd0eb38c88 ]
```

Now i am using `$in` query in mongoDb to fetch all the details as follows:

```
app.models.xxxxx.find({"_id" : {"$in" : objectIds}}, function(err, res){
    if(err){

    } else {
      console.log(res);
    }
  });
```

But its not filtering. All the documents in the collection xxxxx is returning.. Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
when i am running the command in mongo shell:

```
db.xxx.find({ _id: { '$in': [ 57b69c9d4ae615ef0e312af6, 57b69bf477b8e5cd0eb38c88 ] }});
```

It throws error:

```
SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal @(shell):1:35
```

Comment: Well, show your exact query (that gets executed) and documents in the collection. Maybe the filter does select all documents.

Comment: Probably there is problem in converting string to `ObjectId`. Did you tried convert without `new` keyword?

Comment: Slightly off-topic: you can also use [**`.map()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as `var objectIds = expensesIds.map(function(id) { return new ObjectId(id); });`

Comment: Troubleshoot with something like `var findJSON = {"_id" : {"$in" : objectIds}}; console.log("%j", findJSON);` to make sure your searching with what you expect.

Comment: Understood.  I was recommending you log your search criteria, not your results.

Comment: @Wake its showing as `{ _id: { '$in': [ 57b69c9d4ae615ef0e312af6, 57b69bf477b8e5cd0eb38c88 ] } }`

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable `allowExtendedOperators` for your model.

```
//model.json
...
"options": {
    "validateUpsert": true,
    "mongodb": {
      ...
      "allowExtendedOperators": true
    }
  },
...
```

**UPDATE**

Also there is a problem with your filter.

```
app.models.xxxxx.find({where: {"_id" : {"$in" : objectIds}}}, function(err, res){
    if(err){

    } else {
      console.log(res);
    }
  });
```

Also you use built-in operators :

```
app.models.xxxxx.find({where: {id : {inq : objectIds}}}, function(err, res){
        if(err){

        } else {
          console.log(res);
        }
      });
```

Comment: throwing error `TypeError: Argument must be a string`

Comment: @Subburaj and for your `TypeError` exception, you need to send ids as text

Answer (score 1):

if you are using **mongoose** then try this

```
var objectIds = [];
for(var i=0; i<expenseIds.length; i++){
var _id =  mongoose.Types.ObjectId(expenseIds[i]);
objectIds.push(_id);
}
```

or simply you can do this  using MongoDb

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var objectIds = [];
for(var i=0; i<expenseIds.length; i++){
var _id =  ObjectId(expenseIds[i]);
objectIds.push(_id);
}
```

please do let me know if this solves your problem